# Read a perl hash file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file which has the data like below:

output.pl

```
{
    "A" => {
        "name" => "chetan",
        "age" => "28",
    },
    "B" => {
        "name" => "vivek",
        "age" => "31",
    },
};
```

Basically it is hash stored in other file.

How do I write a perl program to load this as a hash in a variable ?

I tried something like this:

```
use Data::Dumper;
use File::Slurp;

my %hash = read_file("output.pl");
print Dumper(keys(%hash));
```

But i see that it says odd number of elements assigned to hash.

Comment: I'm not sure what are the best pratices, so I won't answer. However, an easy way to do it is `my $hash = do "output.pl"`.

Comment: By the way, you should probably `print Dumper \%hash` rather than `print Dumper(keys(%hash))`.

Comment: You could also have a look at [`Config::Hash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MINIMAL/Config-Hash-0.920/lib/Config/Hash.pm).

Comment: I am not sure why you are hesitant with my $hash = do "output.pl" as 'may not be best practice'. It worked like a charm. I will also look in Config::Hash . Thanks.

Comment: Because if `output.pl` contains something like `system "rm -rf /"`, you won't like what `do "output.pl"` just did. Whereas if you were just regularly parsing your file, this wouldn't be an issue. But once again, I don't have any strong opinion on the matter, so I'm just gonna wait for other people to share their thoughts

Comment: @Dada `eval EXPR` has the same issue, so in that respect my answer isn't better...

Comment: There also is [Data::Undump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Undump), but which seems quite fragile.

Comment: `import` is not a perl keyword, you wanted `use`. Avoid File::Slurp, [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load such data using the [do function](https://perldoc.pl/functions/do).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = './output.pl';
my $data = do $file;
# unfortunately 'do' error checking is very fragile
# there is no way to differentiate certain errors from the file returning false or undef
unless ($data) {
  die "couldn't parse $file: $@" if $@;
  die "couldn't do $file: $!" unless defined $data;
  die "$file did not return data";
}
```

This will of course run any arbitrary code within the file, but it is not generally a problem as long as the config file is not writable by anyone who can't also edit the script.

Some other options for config files that don't allow running arbitrary code would be [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::MaybeXS) and [Config::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny).

Make sure to use `./output.pl` and not `output.pl`; without the leading `./` the `do` function will search `@INC` (which no longer contains the current directory in 5.26+) rather than just using the current directory.

If you want to load a file from the same directory as the current file rather than the current working directory (generally a more robust solution) see [Dir::Self](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dir::Self) or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) or similar, with an absolute path so that `@INC` is not searched.

```
use Dir::Self;
my $file = __DIR__ . '/output.pl';

use Path::Tiny;
my $file = path(__FILE__)->realpath->sibling('output.pl');
```

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two problems in your code:

1. you are trying to assign the contents of the file to the hash (instead of evaluating it)
2. your file contains a hash ref, not a hash.

This is one alternative how to load and parse the file contents:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

# replacement for loading external file - not relevant for solution
my $content;
{
    local $/;
    $content = <DATA>;
}
#print "${content}\n";

my $hash = eval $content;
die "eval error: $@" if $@;
#print "${hash}\n";

print Dumper($hash);

exit 0;

__DATA__
{
    "A" => {
        "name" => "chetan",
        "age" => "28",
    },
    "B" => {
        "name" => "vivek",
        "age" => "31",
    },
};
```

Test Run:

```perl
$ perl dummy.pl
$VAR1 = {
          'A' => {
                   'name' => 'chetan',
                   'age' => '28'
                 },
          'B' => {
                   'name' => 'vivek',
                   'age' => '31'
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

As above with Slurp, in a single line.

```
use File::Slurp ;

# no easy way to get current Mojolicious config, so this is a hack
my $config  = eval (read_file( '/etc/smsmap/sms_map.conf'));
```